# Term::Readline::Gnu - how to use complete_internal (if possible..)?

Tags: perl, command-line-interface, readline, cisco

i know how to use custom completion functions with Term::Readline::Gnu (Perl), e.g.

```
str     list_completion_function(str text, int state)
```

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Gnu/Gnu.pm#Custom_Completion
https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC47

```
$attribs->{attempted_completion_function } = sub {
  my ($text, $line, $start, $end) = @_;
  my @cmds = ('one', 'two', 'three');
  $attribs->{completion_word} = \@cmds;
  return $term->completion_matches($text, $attribs->{'list_completion_function'} );
};
```

..but i absolutely don't get how to use complete_internal:

```
int     rl_complete_internal(int what_to_do = TAB)
```

http://search.cpan.org/dist/Term-ReadLine-Gnu/Gnu.pm#Custom_Completion

From the GNU Readline Docs:

*A value of `?' means list the possible completions.`TAB' means do standard completion. `*' means insert all of the possible completions.`!' means to display all of the possible completions (...)*

https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC47

This sounds to me like gnu-readline has a "cisco-like"/router-cli mode - but maybe i get something completely wrong here? And if there is something like this; how can i pass custom completion data to it using Term::Readline::Gnu?

i searched SO, GitHub Code, Google etc pp and am almost certain to miss(understand) something. it would be great if you could lighten me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to use `rl_complete_internal`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use utf8;
use open qw( :std :utf8 );
use warnings;
use Term::ReadLine;

my $term   = Term::ReadLine->new('Test', \*STDIN, \*STDOUT);
$term->ornaments( 0 );
my $attribs = $term->Attribs;
$attribs->{completion_word} = [qw(one two three)];
$attribs->{completion_entry_function} =
    $attribs->{list_completion_function};
$term->add_defun('custom-action', \&my_bind_key_func );
$term->bind_key(ord "\cy", 'custom-action');
my $answer = $term->readline( 'Enter input: ' );
say "You entered: '$answer'";

sub my_bind_key_func {
    my($count, $key) = @_; 
    $term->complete_internal( ord '?' );
    return 0;
}
```

If you type `t` at the prompt and then press `CTRL-y` it will display the two completion candidates, namely `two` and `three`. This is because according to the GNU Readline Library [documentation, section 2.6](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC45):

> int **rl_complete_internal** (*int what_to_do*)
>
> Complete the word
>   at or before point. *what_to_do* says what to do with the completion. A
>   value of `?` means list the possible completions. `TAB` means do
>   standard completion. `*` means insert all of the possible completions.
>   `!` means to display all of the possible completions, if there is more
>   than one, as well as performing partial completion. `@` is similar to
>   `!`, but possible completions are not listed if the possible
>   completions share a common prefix.

Comment: Thanks a lot Håkon! I was on a vacation and stayed away from keyboard - will take a closer look at your code during the next days and then give feedback.